# How to get faces and vertices from vtkVoxelContoursToSurfaceFilter?

Tags: c++, vtk

I am following the  ContoursToSurface (https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/PolyData/ContoursToSurface/) example from VTK website. My question is simply how to get the faces and vertices after vtkVoxelContoursToSurfaceFilter acts on the contours?

The number of different elements (Poly,Verts,Pieces,Points, Lines and Cells) after transforming back the output of filter from ijk coordinate to world coordinate before visualizing:

```cpp
std::cout << "GetNumberOfPolys :" << std::to_string( transformFilter->GetOutput(0)->GetNumberOfPolys()) << std::endl;
std::cout << "GetNumberOfPieces :" << std::to_string( transformFilter->GetOutput(0)->GetNumberOfPieces()) << std::endl;
std::cout << "GetNumberOfLines :" << std::to_string( transformFilter->GetOutput(0)->GetNumberOfLines()) << std::endl;
std::cout << "GetNumberOfVerts :" << std::to_string( transformFilter->GetOutput(0)->GetNumberOfVerts()) << std::endl;
std::cout << "GetNumberOfPoints :" << std::to_string( transformFilter->GetOutput(0)->GetNumberOfPoints()) << std::endl;
std::cout << "GetNumberOfCells :" << std::to_string( transformFilter->GetOutput(0)->GetNumberOfCells()) << std::endl;
```

This outputs the following (which I was not expecting)?

```cpp
GetNumberOfPolys :0
GetNumberOfPieces :1
GetNumberOfLines :0
GetNumberOfVerts :0
GetNumberOfPoints :0
GetNumberOfCells :0
```

Answer (score 1):

The results of `vtkVoxelContoursToSurfaceFilter` is a `vtkPolyData` object. So:

```
pd = transformFilter->GetOutput();

// Extracting vertices:

vertices = pd->GetPoints();

// Extracting faces (cells):

cells = pd->GetCells();
```

You can access individual vertices or cells by specifying their ids:

```
// Extracting point with id = 0:
vert0 = vertices->GetPoint(0);

//Extracting cell with id = 0:
cell0 = cells->GetCell(0);
```